Custom React onScroll animation is not working as expected
I made a simple on scroll animation in React however only the first section (excluding home component all other sections have section) gets the class applied on time. As for the rest of the sections, they get the class applied to them later when I have scrolled halfway past them.
import './App.css';
import Home from './components/Sections/Home';
import Clients from './components/Sections/Clients';
import AboutUs from './components/Sections/AboutUs';
import Career from './components/Sections/Career';
import Discover from './components/Sections/Discover';
import OurWork from './components/Sections/OurWork';
import Testimonial from './components/Sections/Testimonial';
import Plan from './components/Sections/Plan';
import Footer from './components/Sections/Footer';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    const triggerPoint = window.innerHeight / 5 * 4;
    document.querySelector(".trigger").style.top = triggerPoint + "px";
    const handleScroll = () => checkSections(triggerPoint)
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    checkSections(triggerPoint);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };

  }, []);

  function checkSections(triggerPoint){
    const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
    console.log("window.innerheight",window.innerHeight);
    console.log("triggerpoint",triggerPoint);
    
    sections.forEach(section => {
      const sectionTop = section.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      console.log("sectiontop",sectionTop);

      if(sectionTop < triggerPoint){
        section.classList.add("on-scroll");
      }else{
        section.classList.remove("on-scroll")
      }
    })

  }

  return (
    <div id="App" style={{position: "relative"}}>
      <div className='trigger' style={{position: "fixed", left: "100px", background: "white", zIndex: "99", width: "50px", height: "50px"}}></div>
      <Home />
      <Clients />
      <AboutUs />
      <Career />
      <Discover />
      <OurWork />
      <Testimonial />
      <Plan />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );

}

export default App;


I tried to understand the problem myself by visualizing the triggerPoint on the screen but due to inexperience I couldn't understand what the problem was.

Hi, Just by looking at your code, I could tell the problem is your triggerPoint you might need to reduce it

@D.lola the trigger point is quite low already and it works perfectly fine for the client component and only works properly for other components when those component leave the trigger point but the problem comes when the components enter the triggerpoint

You are imperatively adding classes, this is not a very React-ey way of doing things and can cause problems if you're controlling the class names from both React and vainlla js. Regardless I think this is an XY problem; you're asking to fix your attempt at a solution instead of a solution to the root problem. I think intersection observer would be much better than "trigger point" for your use case.

@ZohaibMushtaq maybe you could use throttle from React

@Asplund i used intersection observer as you suggested and it works and i have pasted it in the answer so review it a bit and thanks

After using Intersection Observer as suggested by @Asplund I included Intersection Observer into the code and it works perfectly how I want.
The final code is:
useEffect(() => {
  const discovers = document.querySelectorAll(".discover");
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
    (entries) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        entry.target.classList.toggle("on-scroll", entry.isIntersecting);
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          observer.unobserve(entry.target);
        }
      });
    },
    {
      threshold: 0.5,
    },
  );
  discovers.forEach((discover) => {
    observer.observe(discover);
  });
  return () => {
    discovers.forEach((discover) => {
      observer.unobserve(discover);
    });
  };
}, []);

It will work in React, if you are using vanilla js copy the code from within the useEffect.
